Delay in the shared library constructor invocation when pre-loaded with the application
I was working on making an interception library (on Linux); which I pre-load before I run the application that I need to use it for. This is intended to perform redirection.
In my library, I have the __attribute__ constructor(()) to set up the environment that is needed to be run before any resolutions to the calls defined in my library are made.
Now, my assumption was that at runtime, this constructor will be called before any resolutions have been made to the functions that I have defined in this library. For example, let's say that I was intercepting the ioctl function. My assumption was that the dynamic linker would only resolve any calls (and call them) ONLY after the __attribute__ constructor(()) has run; or at-least run the ctor when the first call to ioctl was made, and the loader is resolving it.
But to my surprise, it happens to be the case that the ctor is delayed (on average by 17-30 milliseconds). The ctor is indeed called, but it is delayed. There are calls redirected to my version of ioctl before the ctor has even executed.
I have made attempts to understand the stuff that happens between the program getting loaded, but it was challenging to come to any conclusion. I would really appreciate it to know the details behind such an execution.
The way I compile my shared library is:
g++ my_lib.cpp -shared -fPIC -o my_lib.so

And then, I load it with my application as:
LD_PRELOAD="./my_lib.so" ./{application_executable}



Now, my assumption was that at runtime, this constructor will be called before any resolutions have been made to the functions that I have defined in this library.

That is indeed a reasonable expectation.

But to my surprise, it happens to be the case that the ctor is delayed (on average by 17-30 milliseconds). The ctor is indeed called, but it is delayed. There are calls redirected to my version of ioctl before the ctor has even executed.

There are several possible explanations:

You are mis-interpreting your observations
The ld-linux itself calls ioctl as part of its own initialization
Your constructor routine calls ioctl itself
You create threads which run in parallel with your constructor
Something else I am not thinking of ...

Without further details, it's impossible to tell which of the above reasons is the real one.
One way to debug this is to put an infinite loop into your ioctl interposer (see e.g. this answer), and run the program. It should block. Once it does, attach debugger to it, and find out where ioctl is called from.
